# How did he set up time bomb?

Tags: plot-explanation, last-action-hero

In Last Action Hero (1993), Jack Slater actually take cards on dead body, he sees it. it has 5,4,.... etc

[image]

So he realized that Benedict planted Time Bomb, then he ran away. My Question is: How Benedict exactly planted a time bomb so that count down matches numbers on the card?

Here is Final Explosion.

[image]

Comment: IIRC the action movie within the movie is pretty much an over the top, unrealistic spoof, so this seems par for the course. But it's always possible that a timer was triggered the second Jack touched the cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The villain worked out exactly how long it would take for Slater to find the cards and flip through them, and set the timer on the bomb appropriately. It's not meant to be realistic, since this is in the "movie world" where you have cartoon cats and black-and-white Humphrey Bogart.

In any case, he obviously miscalculated, since Slater had time to escape the explosion.